# Member variable vs Field for a variable which is called frequently C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I'm looking at a Method member variable that should realistically only have the scope of Method and shouldn't be accessed anywhere else and thus standard coding practices say it should stay as a method variable. However, It is part of a Unity project I am working on and the Method gets called pretty much every Update. I am fairly new to all of this but my understanding is that due to its small scope the variable will likely be destroyed and the memory de-allocated each time garbage collection is called and reallocated next time the method is called, which will be the next frame, seemingly a waste. This will be further compounded by the script being attached to multiple GameObjects all doing this.

As I said, new to this and my understanding of how the Garbage collection process occurs is limited, (and I'm potentially chasing optimization I don't need) but is there a best practice for this before I get too far along?

i.e.
This

```
    public class MyClass {

    int var1;

    //called every frame
    private void Update() {
        var1 = 10*2;
    }
```

vs

```
    public class MyClass {
    //called every frame
    private void Update() {
        int var1;
        var1 = 10*2;
    }
```

Comment: Variables declared inside methods (aka functions) are not "member variables". A field _is_ a member-variable (unless it's `const` or immutable in some way, ofc). A value-typed variable declared inside a method (e.g. `int`, `bool`, etc) lives on the stack, not the GC heap, and so there's no garbage-collection involved at all (ignoring closures and async methods for now; also reference-types are handled differently, but the important thing here is lexical scope, not necessary GC lifetime).

Comment: Also, this article should be required reading for everyone using .NET: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html

Comment: Thanks @Dai, that article is incredibly useful on many fronts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general rule of thumb is it should be scoped within the method if it is not needed by anything outside the method, i.e. the member level.